# Separate string by characters in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to separate characters from any given strings and making subsring with it. For example,

```
str='abcd' => 'ab','bc','cd'
```

Here is my solution,

```
str='abcdef'
a=[]
for i in range(len(str)):
  a.append(str[i:i+2])
a.remove(a[-1])
print(a)
```

This works but I would like to know better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic? Do you want all the substrings of length 2?

Comment: Yes, as I showed the output should be: ab, bc, cd, de, ef

Comment: `[str[p:p+2] for p in range(len(str)-1)]`

Comment: Unrelated, but `str` is a builtin function. Do not use it as a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution without external modules (like your implementation, but cleaner).

```
[my_str[i:i+2] for i in range(len(my_str) - 1)]
```

so

```
In [3]: my_str='abcdef'

In [4]: [my_str[i:i+2] for i in range(len(my_str) - 1)]
Out[4]: ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [**`zip()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (Built-in):

```
[f'{x}{y}' for x, y in zip(s, s[1:])]
```

**Code**:

```
s = 'abcdef'

print([f'{x}{y}' for x, y in zip(s, s[1:])]) # Python 3.6+. For previous versions, use below line.
# [x + y for x, y in zip(s, s[1:])] 

# Outputs: ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef']
```